# Configure ssh for Jenkins inside Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh

i have a jenkins that run inside a docker container (on a server A) and i want to publish an artifact over ssh in a server B.

I have installed the plugin "publish over ssh" in Jenkins but i don't know how to configure the ssh.

I guess that i must generate a public/private key on the server A and send my public key on the server B. But for which user?

I have a user jenkins on the server B but not on the server A. Should i generate the key with the same user that run the docker on the server A? Where should I put my keys?

Thanks.

Comment: Please attach your Dockerfile or image name that you running, so that anyone can make recommendations.